# How do I extract fingerprints from .ssh/known_hosts?

Tags: ssh, security, fingerprint, known-hosts

My laptop has a well-populated `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. I'd like to leverage that when connecting to remote hosts from my desktop, since tracking down the fingerprints can be a real chore. However, I can't seem to find a way to ask `ssh-keygen` or `ssh-keyscan` to tell me the locally-known fingerprint for known hosts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

#### Try this command:

```
% ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts

2048 c2:e7:c0:9f:cd:c8:54:88:ac:b3:6b:a6:51:73:2b:e3 mach1,192.168.1.3 (RSA)
2048 a2:5e:8c:4e:2e:be:be:eb:23:12:5e:fe:6c:4b:23:dd mach2,192.168.1.1 (RSA)
1024 ae:5f:bc:e3:33:c3:dd:45:1e:18:1a:46:d1:d6:d2:39 mach3,192.168.1.6 (RSA)
...
...
```

#### just want a single host:

```
% ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F mach1
2048 c2:e7:c0:9f:cd:c8:54:88:ac:b3:6b:a6:51:73:2b:e3 mach1 (RSA)
```

#### Resources

http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/users/49503

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you could use `-l` with a known_hosts file.

Here's a version that even better addresses my question: `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F example.com`

Comment: Glad it helped. 2 heads are better than one 8-).

Comment: Incidentally, the reason -F is important for me is that whatever version of SSH I have installed has hashed all the hostnames in the known_hosts file. I can't just grep for the line I want. (This is a useful security measure if someone ever gets my private key -- they're less likely to figure out what machines it can get them into.)

Comment: It is worth noting that recent versions of openssh default to a SHA256 hash. To get the older md5 hash, use the `-E md5` option.

Comment: And if a non-standard port is used: `[example.com]:1234`

Comment: Another +1. This is something I've been looking for "how do you check fingerprint of a remote ssh server on the client machine"..... or "how does ssh client know the remote server's fingerprint has changed"

Comment: To get host key fingerprints for an SSH server (replace example IP with your server's IP or hostname): `ssh-keyscan  123.123.12.34  | ssh-keygen -l -f -`